# Write protect VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

The code below when run on Visual Studio 2017 (Win 2010 OS) produces a write protect media error, when attempting to save to my USB drive.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("G:\Test\Test.txt", True)
        file.WriteLine("TEST1")
        file.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("OK")
 End Sub
```

Comment: Please google "usb memory stick disable write protect" to get ahead.  And ponder for a bit how to know for a fact that it got mapped to the G: drive on your user's machine.

Answer (score -1):

Try running your app as Admin.

- Right click on .exe, then "Run as admin".

[image]